# Sonar Lint how to suppress issues on commented code only

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have this piece of code.

```
    public String createElasticSearchQuery(MultiValuedHashMap queryMap){
        SearchSourceBuilder elasticSearchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        BoolQueryBuilder esQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder= buildMatchQuery(queryMap);
        esQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
    
        //regular expression
        RegexpQueryBuilder regxQueryBuilder= buildRegualarExpressionQuery(queryMap);
        esQueryBuilder.must(regxQueryBuilder);
        return elasticSearchSourceBuilder.query(esQueryBuilder).toString();
    }
```

My senior wants me to comment out few lines of code as shown below (He is not allowing me to delete the code as this functionality will be needed later), As this functionality is not needed as of now. The problem is Sonarqube/SonarLint throws it as a Major issue and does not allow us to merge the code to our master branch.

```
public String createElasticSearchQuery(MultiValuedHashMap queryMap){
        SearchSourceBuilder elasticSearchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        BoolQueryBuilder esQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder= buildMatchQuery(queryMap);
        esQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
    
        //regular expression
        //RegexpQueryBuilder regxQueryBuilder= buildRegualarExpressionQuery(queryMap);
        //esQueryBuilder.must(regxQueryBuilder);
        return elasticSearchSourceBuilder.query(esQueryBuilder).toString();
    }
```

Now, If I use the annotation @SuppressWarnings("ALL")  then all the errors that will get generated will be suppressed. Is there an way for us to just suppress the issues related to commenting few lines of code.

Comment: "He is not allowing me to delete the code as this functionality will be needed later" 1) get it back from version control; 2) it's not exactly hard to rewrite, is it? 3) what's that line doing anyway? That there is a useful side effect in that line is... surprising (e.g. you're not using the return value, so the only reason to have it at all is because there is a side effect).

Comment: @AndyTurner,  1) Its hard to reason. 2) The code is slightly complex but do-able. 3) I have updated the code I have missed the code while framing the question.

Comment: Have you told your senior colleague of the problem that their request creates, and asked them to suggest a solution?

Comment: @AndyTurner, They have no solution in mind. But wanted me to find a solution for these.

Comment: I think, I got it. @SuppressWarnings("squid:S125"). I obtained the number from the issue which gets created by SonarLint.